# facing core dump while assigning the empty string to string variable

Tags: c++

I am facing core dump when my application is trying to write the text into a file. It is using string operations as shown in the code. When multiple thread try to call this function and try to write to log file then my application is dumping core. I have gone through different forums and tried to search for any problem in string assignment. I have seen that some of us have commented on that string assignment statement as it is not good to use. Instead use string member function.

**Function:**

```
void Debug::writeToFile()
{
if(_ptrMutex == NULL)
    _ptrMutex = new Mutex();
_ptrMutex->getLock();
write(_fd,_cacheStr.c_str(),_cacheStr.size());
_cacheStr = ""; //flush the write string
_ptrMutex->releaseLock();
}
```

**cacheWriteString**

```
bool Debug::cacheWriteString(string strIn)
{
if(_ptrMutex == NULL)
    _ptrMutex = new CndMutex();
_ptrMutex->getLock();
char timeStamp[100];

struct timeval  tv;
struct tm   tm;

if (gettimeofday(&tv, NULL)==0 && localtime_r((time_t*)&(tv.tv_sec), &tm)) {
    int ret = strftime(timeStamp,sizeof(timeStamp),"%F-%T",&tm);
    snprintf(timeStamp+ret, sizeof(timeStamp)-ret, ".%03ld", tv.tv_usec/1000);
} else
Time::getTimeStamp(timeStamp,100);
_cacheStr = _cacheStr + "[" + timeStamp + "] " + strIn;
if(_cacheStr.size() >= _maxCacheSize)
{
    _ptrMutex->releaseLock();
    return true;
}
_ptrMutex->releaseLock();
return false;
}
```

**This functions is called as**

```
void Debug::LOG_PRINT_ERROR(char* ptrFormat,...)
{
va_list argList;
va_start(argList,ptrFormat);

if(_logType == CONSOLE_LOG) //console log
{
    cout<<"#### [ERROR] ";
    vprintf(ptrFormat,argList);
    cout<<endl;
}
else if(_logType == SYS_LOG)// [syslog]
{
    syslog(LOG_ERR,"%s","[ERROR]####");
    vsyslog(LOG_ERR,ptrFormat,argList);
}
else if(_logType == FILE_LOG)
{
    char str[1024];
    //SBYTE4 ret = vsprintf(str,ptrFormat,argList);
    SBYTE4 ret = vsnprintf(str,1023,ptrFormat,argList);
    str[1023]='\0';
    if(ret > -1)
    {
        string dataStr = "[ERROR]####";
        dataStr = dataStr +str+"\n";
        if(cacheWriteString(dataStr))
        {
            if(chkFile() == DIM_PASS)
            {
                writeToFile();
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"#### LOG_ERROR() Unable to Write Data To File: "<<_fileName <<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"#### LOG_ERROR() Output Error Is Encountered: "<<_fileName <<endl;
    }
}
va_end(argList);
```

}

**Core Dump details as follows:**

```
Thread 1 (Thread 8426):
#0  0x00a2a402 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x0072bdf0 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x0072d701 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x0545651a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x05456552 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x0545668a in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x053ed1ef in std::__throw_length_error(char const*) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x0543211d in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x05433e28 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_mutate(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x05433fca in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace_safe(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x05434065 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*, unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#11 0x0815e9a8 in Debug::writeToFile() ()
#12 0x08161866 in Debug::LOG_PRINT_ERROR(char*, ...) ()
#13 0x0812bcc6 in DimInternalMsgHandler::handlePeerStatusIndication(DimPeerStatusInd*) ()
#14 0x0812c52a in DimInternalMsgHandler::handleInternalMessage(unsigned char*, int) ()
#15 0x0812aa05 in DimDanIfController::handleInMessage(NwPacket&) ()
#16 0x081ab28f in WorkerThreadPool::onEvent(int, nxs_util::EventMessage64*) ()
#17 0x0021dd94 in nxs_util::EventHandler64::workerProc(int) () from /home/nextgen/NXS/lib/libnxsutil.so
#18 0x001c193e in nxs_util::WorkerThread::run() () from /home/nextgen/NXS/lib/libnxsutil.so
#19 0x001c5b36 in nxs_util::Thread::__Thread_run(void*) () from /home/nextgen/NXS/lib/libnxsutil.so
#20 0x0087f832 in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#21 0x007d4e0e in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

We are suspecting that there is problem of <_cacheStr = "";> statement we are using in our code. We are thinking to change to _cacheStr.clear(); But we are not able to reproduce this core now.

If anyone has any idea about it or faced it please let us know.

Thank you very much for your inputs.

Comment: A small note: You have possible a race-condition in `writeToFile` when creating the mutex. If two threads can come into the function and one is pre-empted after the check but before the creation, then both threads can create the mutex.

Answer (score 1):

This looks really, really dodgy:

```
if(_ptrMutex == NULL)
    _ptrMutex = new Mutex();
```

What if two threads enter this block and dynamically create their own mutexes? Is there any reason that you can't create a single mutex on initialization and avoid the "create mutex" race condition?

Comment: This is dodgy to be sure. You can use `pthread_do_once` to do this properly if there is no better place for initialization.

Comment: This is valid in the initialization time as this point is valid when two thread are coming during initilization time. But here application is running continuously and then dump core. since Debug class is having single instance so always last mutex will get used across the threads. I accept that this code should not be there. But  crash will happen at initization time.

Comment: @user1177666: I'm sorry, but it's not safe if two threads are coming into this function at initialization time. Anything could happen, such as double unlocking one mutex and breaking the synchronization object totally. This could cause a breaking side effect at just about any subsequent point it time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I take this point into my account. But at present whatever the core dump happened is not because of this issue i suppose. What do you think?

Comment: @user1177666: Unless you fix this issue, you'll never know for sure. On the face of it `_cacheStr = ""` should not fail unless the object has been corrupted or unless you performing some thread unsafe actions. Given this, you really need to fix all the potential threading errors that you find. I don't see any concrete evidence that this error cannot be the root cause of your crash.

Answer (score 0):

If any other thread can access `_cacheStr` (even just to examine it) while `_ptrMutex` is not held, this could easily lead to a crash like this.

Comment: Other thread has to go through this this mutex locking mechanism unless thread working on releases it. So all the threads will go normal locking and unlocking mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

i see that there is locking for the function writeToFile, and the cacheStr should be a global variable, but i do not see the function cacheWriteString, so i think it is a race-condition for the cacheStr variable which is not protected in the function cacheWriteString. 2 threads may access/modify the string at the same time.