# code dump in string assignment

Tags: c++, multithreading, string, crash, centos

I am getting core dump in following part of code:

```
void Debug::writeToFile()
{
 _ptrMutex->getLock();
 write(_fd,_cacheStr.c_str(),_cacheStr.size());
 _cacheStr = ""; //flush the write string
 _ptrMutex->releaseLock();
}
```

And the core occurred once and stack dump is as follows

```
Thread 1 (Thread 8426):
#0  0x00a2a402 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x0072bdf0 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x0072d701 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x0545651a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x05456552 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x0545668a in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x053ed1ef in std::__throw_length_error(char const*) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x0543211d in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x05433e28 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_mutate(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x05433fca in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace_safe(unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x05434065 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*, unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#11 0x0815e9a8 in Debug::writeToFile() ()
#12 0x08161866 in Debug::LOG_PRINT_ERROR(char*, ...) ()
#13 0x0812bcc6 in DimInternalMsgHandler::handlePeerStatusIndication(DimPeerStatusInd*) ()
#14 0x0812c52a in DimInternalMsgHandler::handleInternalMessage(unsigned char*, int) ()
#15 0x0812aa05 in DimDanIfController::handleInMessage(NwPacket&) ()
```

Comment: The core dump is caused by an uncaught exception. Do you think you could wrap the function in an exception handler and print the .what() message? As to why the exception happens, I don't know - but the most likely is that your string object is invalid when you are trying to write to it. I'd recommend using a memory debugger such as Valgrind.

Comment: Looking at the code in libstdc++, the exception message is probably not going to say much. But the exception thrown indicates that the requested size for the new string buffer needed in your string assignment is larger than the max size of a string, which makes no sense unless you have corrupted memory somewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [facing core dump while assigning the empty string to string variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061539/facing-core-dump-while-assigning-the-empty-string-to-string-variable)

Comment: Please do not re-post when you don't get an answer right away.

Comment: We are not able to reproduce this issue. We are struggling to reproduce it.

Comment: Could you please send the link for libstdc++ link? My gcc version is gcc version 3.4.3 20041212 (Red Hat 3.4.3-9.EL4).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the problem is with `writeToFile()` itself.

I can see several possibilities:

1. The first possibility is that `_cacheStr` has become corrupted, possibly due to a memory bug elsewhere.
2. The second possibility is that there is a concurrent modification of `_cacheStr` by another thread. I can see that `writeToFile()` is protected by a mutex, but any other place where `_cacheStr` can be modified would need to do the same.

Comment: There are Debug class member functions and all the functions use mutex lock before doing any operations on its data members.